# complete vlookup of weekly reports

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

i complete a weekly report where you run multiple vlookups against a couple of different reports. i would like to be able to pick the file to run the vlookup against, as it will change from week to week. below is what i have so far, but I keep getting Runtime errors, and when it does run, it lookup up the same value for each row. Lastly, I am a beginner at VBA, so i apologize in advance if i have made some rookie mistakes.

```
Sub VlookOne()
Dim filenm As Variant
Dim MyBook1 As Workbook
Dim MyBook2 As Workbook
Dim myTableArray
Dim rowcnt
Dim beginrow
Dim lastrow

beginrow = 4
lastrow = 200
Set MyBook1 = ThisWorkbook
filenm = Application.GetOpenFilename
'the workbook im trying to run the vlookup against
Set MyBook2 = Workbooks.Open(filenm)
    With MyBook2
        Set myTableArray = MyBook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:M300")
    End With

    For rowcnt = beginrow To lastrow
    MyBook1.Activate
    Range("M4").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(Range("A4"), myTableArray, 13, False)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next rowcnt

End Sub
```

Comment: What error, specifically, do you get, at what line? Also, if I read correctly, your `for rowcnt`  loop does the same thing over and over.  You change the `selection` at the end, but then at the start of the next loop, choose cell `M4`...

Comment: I would define your variables `myTableArray` as range, and `rowcnt`, `beginrow` and `lastrow` as integers. Also I don't see the need for a loop, If you want to vlookup based on a range you could look at using `MyBook1.Range("M4:M200").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A4," & myTableArray & ", 13, False)"`. Although I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: unless ThisWorkbook only has one sheet you should full qualify range references with the parent sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue of the value being repeated over change the line

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(Range("A4"), myTableArray, 13, False)
```

to

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & rowcnt), myTableArray, 13, False)
```

This should tell VLOOKUP to use the value from the active row, instead of looking up the value in the cell 'A4' all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should fully qualify your range references to avoid implicit activesheet references. Remove your ActiveCell and .Select/.Activate lines as these increase overhead and slow your code. Use your row variable to both refer to current row in loop and avoid overwriting as you currently are:

```
With MyBook1.Worksheets("Sheet1")            '<==change as required   
    For rowcnt = beginrow To lastRow  
        .Cells(RowCount, "M") = Application.VLookup(.Cells(RowCount, "A"), myTableArray, 13, False)   
    Next rowcnt   
End With
```

You may also want to add in error handling for if LookUp match not found.